# SwiftUI - offset is wrong

Tags: swiftui

I came across this weird thing where I overlay two diffrent views. These two views contain a ForEach loop where it creates a Rectangle element. The offset of this rectangle is determined by the index of the ForEach loop * a set height variable of 30. One of the view's rectangles have a height of 1 while he other view's rectangle has as a height of this height variable. This should create a rectangle with a border. But it doesn't, the two views don't match up?

I have no clue why this happens. Of course if I wanted a Rectangle with a border I could do that but that's not my point. Im genuinely curious as why this happens. Code is below.

First view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 10) { i in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 1)
                    .offset(y: CGFloat(height*i))
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test()
    }
}
```

Second View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct test2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { i in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(height: CGFloat(height))
                    .offset(y: CGFloat(height*i))
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct test2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test2()
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

public var height = 30

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        test2()
            .overlay(test())
                
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: What's the `offset` for? Try just removing it

Answer (score 1):

use this in test:

```
.offset(y: CGFloat((height*i)-i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Say both `test` and `test2` starts at `y = 0`.

- Your first green rectangle locates between y=0 and y=1, and offset by 30
- Your second green rectangle locates between y=31 and y=32
- Third between y=62 and y=63

  ⋮

---

- Your first red rectangle locates between y=0 and y=30, and offset by 30
- Your second red rectangle locates between y=60 and y=90

  ⋮

---

Now you see the problem, then don't match.

To solve it, you could change the offsets in `test`:

```
struct test : View {
     ⋮
    Rectangle()
        .offset(y: CGFloat((height - 1) * i))
     ⋮
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's what I have in my answer:  (x*i)-i = i*(x-1)

Comment: @workingdog I know, I upvoted yours, but I think it's good to explain why there's an offset to begin with.

Comment: fair enough, certainly good to explain it. I often lack this in my answers.

Comment: Thank you so much! Im very new to Swift, got my first mac a couple of days ago. Otherwise im do web development and there this would have worked. Thats why I was so confused. Thanks again!

Comment: @bappobrad A side note, I would've used `.padding(.bottom, height)` instead of `.offset`, and maybe used `ZStack{ test2() test() }` instead of `.overlay`